# Как установить причину зависания ноутбука на Linux mint при выходе из режима suspend?

Tags: linux-mint

поставил себе Linux mint 18.2 xfce на свежий Lenovo IdeaPad 110-14IBR. после выхода из suspend-режима система иногда наглухо зависает и спасает только выключить-включить. можно ли установить в чем именно проблема: в железе или в операционке и как-то глянуть в логах на каком этапе случается сбой?

Comment: Логи живут тут /var/log Гляньте в message dmesg syslog